K8s Ingress Proxy Body Size Annotation Quotes Removed After Applying and Getting 413 Error
I'm working with a Kubernetes (k8s) Ingress and need to increase the upload size limit. I added the following annotation to my Ingress definition:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: '200m'

However, I still receive a 413 Request Entity Too Large error when trying to upload files.
Additionally, I've noticed that the quotes around the proxy-body-size value are removed after the Ingress is applied. Here is my full Ingress configuration:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-uat
  namespace: app-uat
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'false'
    nginx.org/redirect-to-https: 'false'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: '200m'
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts: 
      - mydomain.com
      secretName: mydomain-tls
  rules:
    - host: mydomain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /core/
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: app-core
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /proxy/
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: app-proxy
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /panel/
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: admin-panel
                port:
                  number: 80

Questions:

Why am I still getting the 413 Payload Too Large error despite adding the nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size annotation?
Why are the quotes around the proxy-body-size value removed after the Ingress is applied, and does this affect the functionality? Because I've read somewhere that the nginx annotations should be quoted.


On (2), since the string 200m unambiguously isn't a number or Boolean or JSON-ish data structure, it doesn't matter in the YAML syntax whether it's quoted or not.

Can you check if the provided SO link is useful to you.

@KiranKotturi Thanks Kiran but no; it completely disables the limit which is not what I want. However, I've solved the problem and will post the solution!

@Behnia FB , for the better visibility of the community you can post the resolved steps as an Answer.

As I was using NginxInc Ingress class, I had to use the correct annotation, which is nginx.org. So needed to use client-max-body-size.
So the result would be nginx.org/client-max-body-size:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'false'
    nginx.org/redirect-to-https: 'false'
    nginx.org/client-max-body-size: 300m

